# Moment problem with wrong solution

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, hypergeometric-functions

I will write a problem with an answer that apparently is wrong. My question would be what is wrong with this solution.

Define $$B(s)=\sum_{i=0}^s{{2\,s-i-1\choose s-1}\frac {i}{s}{5}^{i}{2}^{s-i}}$$ for integers $s>0$.
The problem is to find $f(x)$ such that 
$$\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}x^{2s}f(x)dx=B(s)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}x^{2s-1}f(x)dx=0.\tag{$*$}$$

To find $f(x)$ we can use Zeilberg's algorithm and obtain that $B(s)$ satisfy the following recurrence relation
$$25\,B \left( s \right) -3\,B \left( s+1 \right) =10\,{\frac {{8}^{s}
\Gamma  \left( s+1/2 \right) }{\sqrt {\pi }\Gamma  \left( s+2 \right) 
}}.$$

Now, we can write the right hand side as an integral $$10\,{\frac {{8}^{s}
\Gamma  \left( s+1/2 \right) }{\sqrt {\pi }\Gamma  \left( s+2 \right) 
}}=\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}{\frac {5{x}^{2\,s}\sqrt {8-{x}^{2}}}{2\pi }}dx.\tag{$**$}$$

Now replacing (*) and (**) in the recurrence, we obtain
$$25\,\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}x^{2s}f(x)dx -3\,\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}x^{2s+2}f(x)dx=\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}{\frac {5{x}^{2\,s}\sqrt {8-{x}^{2}}}{2\pi }}dx.$$

Taking derivatives and solving for $f(x)$, we obtain
$$f(x)={\frac {5\sqrt {8-{x}^{2}}}{2\pi \, \left( 25-3\,{x}^{2} \right) }}.$$

It seems everything is correct to me. However, if we take $s=1$
$$\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}x^{2}f(x)dx=\frac{20}{9},$$ but $$B(1)=5.$$

In fact it is wrong for every $s$ I fix.

Would you be kind and give me some ideas on how to fix my solution to find $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your last step "Taking derivatives and solving for etc." Namely, the display before this sentence can be rewritten as
$$\int_{-2\sqrt{2}}^{2\sqrt{2}}x^{2s}g(x)dx = 0,\qquad s=1,2,3,\dots,\tag{1}$$
where
$$g(x):=(25-3x^2)f(x)-\frac {5\sqrt {8-{x}^{2}}}{2\pi}.$$
From here you conclude that $g(x)$ is identically zero, which is bad logic. For example, any odd function $g:[-2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2}]\to\mathbb{R}$, i.e. one that satisfies $g(-x)=-g(x)$, automatically satisfies (1).

**P.S.** The OP added the condition that $f(x)$ is even, which makes $g(x)$ even as well. In this case $g(x)$ is identically zero as the OP claimed originally (assuming of course that $f(x)$ is continuous). So the conclusion is that $f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: I see. In my case $f(x)$ is an even function, because the odd moments are zero. How can I recover $f(x)$ then?

Comment: @LuHell: Well, if $f(x)$ is an even function, then so is $g(x)$, and then we get that $g(x)$ is identically zero (at least when $g(x)$ is $x^2$ times a continuous function). So in this case the only candidate for $f(x)$ is the one that you indicate. However, this $f(x)$ does not work, which means that no $f(x)$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: No $f(x)$ satisfy that? I fail to see why.

Comment: @LuHell: Because this is what your argument gives. Your initial conditions lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @LuHell: We don't even need that $g(x)$ is $x^2$ times a continuous function (I overlooked this). Simply, if $g(x)$ is continuous and even, then so is $x^2 g(x)$, and by (1) and the Weierstrass approximation theorem it is orthogonal to itself. So $x^2 g(x)$ is identically zero, hence so is $g(x)$.

Comment: That makes sense. Would that $f(x)$ have a meaning?

Comment: @LuHell: I don't understand your question. The function $f(x)$ you are looking for does not exist, so it makes no sense to ask what kind of meaning it has. It does not exist, period.

Comment: The $f(x)$ that satisfy the recurrence relation with the integral exists. It does not match $B(s)$, though. My question is what it could mean in terms of $B(s)$

Comment: @LuHell: I don't know. The moments of $f(x)$ are returned by Mathematica in terms of the gamma-function and a hypergeometric function, but I am not sure it can be brought into a shape like $B(s)$. Apriori it is just another function that satisfies the display before your $(**)$. At any rate, I answered your original question, so it should be closed. You can ask another question as to what the moments of your $f(x)$ have to do with $B(s)$.

Comment: The second-limit theorem of Frechet claims that the measure $dF$, where $F'=f(x)dx$ should exist, since the moments are finite.

Comment: @LuHell: The measures $f(x)dx$ are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $dx$. Not all measures are of that kind! Even if you allow general (positive) measures (not just the absolutely continuous ones), there is a necessary (and sufficient) positivity condition for the moments, i.e. they cannot be arbitrary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem (The positivity condition is not needed for signed measures.)

Comment: See Thm 2.8 of http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/ntharm15/handouts/graphs/mckay_EigenvalueLargeRandomGraphs.pdf

Comment: @LuHell: This theorem is about general measures, while you are looking for absolutely continuous measures of the form $f(x)dx$. For most sequences of moments there is no function $f(x)$ that you are looking for. Example: if $\int_0^1 x^r dE(x)=2^{-r}$ for each $r$, then $dE(x)$ is the Dirac measure at $1/2$. This measure is not absolutely continuous with respect to $dx$ (in fact it is concentrated on a single point), hence there is no function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^1 x^r f(x) dx=2^{-r}$ for each $r$. At any rate, this site is not about teaching basic measure theory.

Comment: @LuHell: Likewise, Theorem 2.4 in this paper features a general Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $dF(x)$. If $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable, then of course $dF(x)=F'(x)dx$. Now $F(x)$ is increasing here, so $F'(x)$ exists at almost every point, but it may well happen that $F'(x)=0$ almost everywhere, in which case $dF(x)$ will be very far from $F'(x)dx$. Read about singular measures in any textbook on measure theory. BTW it is odd that you do not accept your own proof that $f(x)$ does not exist. It is like when the Pythagoreans could not accept that $x^2=2$ has no solution in rationals!